# How do loud speaker manufacturers achieve frequency response ranges as low as 20Hz for its speakers and headphones?

Tags: diy, loudspeakers

I'm in the process of learning about building speakers myself, and noticed that there isn't a single speaker driver that is marketed to have frequency response ranges that drop to as low as 20Hz. I think the lowest that I've seen is in the ballpark of 30Hz.

Sony markets their devices to have frequency response ranges to go as low as 20Hz.

I own two products of theirs, both having frequency response ranges from 20Hz, to 20kHz. I play a 20Hz tone, and sure enough, I can hear something.

But on my MacBook Pro, I don't hear anything. So, I guess Sony is doing something right. Or perhaps it's all marketing.

If I understand it correctly, as frequencies drop below a certain point, it's not like the volume cuts off abruptly. Instead, I believe that it's a gradual drop in volume, and we should have the opportunity to throw in an equalizer to boost the lower frequencies. But that's just a guess.

I'm new to building speakers, and I would like to learn more in the ballpark of what Sony (and others) is doing for them to confidently market their products to have such frequency ranges.

Answer (score 2):

**Engineering.**

Speaker manufacturers  have   research and development  departments staffed with engineers that spend a lot of time to develop  **crossovers** (*capacitors,resistors and coils*)  in conjunction with **drivers** that can  be tailored to play  a lot or a little  of  the  sound wave spectrum.

Your Macbook is unlikely to have anything other then just a **VERY small speaker**, Very small speakers without  a crossover in a VERY small space can not reach the low end of the spectrum.

[Understanding Loudspeaker Frequency Response](https://www.audioholics.com/loudspeaker-design/understanding-loudspeaker-frequency-response)

[Building a Do-It-Yourself Loudspeaker Design](https://www.audioholics.com/diy-audio/building-a-do-it-yourself-loudspeaker-design)

*The truth in spec sheets on speakers has long been   very dubious.*